# Are Cauchy sequences natural?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces, universal-property

When definining the completion of a field $k$ by a norm one typically uses Cauchy sequences. More specifically the completion of $k$ is defined as the set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in $k$. It seems natural that one would want Cauchy sequences to be convergent in order to say that the field "does not have holes". However I have never seen a justification that would make Cauchy sequences a canonical choice of type of sequence that should be used in the definition of completion. Perhaps there are other equally valid choices to define a completion and they would yield a non-isomorphic field?

Are Cauchy sequences indeed a canonical choice for a definition of the completion?
Is there a formulation of the completion by a norm as a universal object in some category or any way to fit Cauchy sequences into a natural setting?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to convince yourself of the following fact: any convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence. So if there is a sequence that becomes convergent after completion it must be a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @ZhenLin yes that is true but aren't there any other interesting facts that should be satisfied by all convergent sequences? Why isn't the Cauchy property just one among many possible ones?

Comment: Whatever other interesting facts there may be, they are either equivalent to being a Cauchy sequence, or they are implied by being a Cauchy sequence. It's just logic.

Comment: @ZhenLin why would it be logic? it seems like a pretty strong statement to say that there are no other weaker conditions implied by convergence in a general normed space. My question is precisely about this.

Comment: Cauchy is a statement about "two terms should be arbitrarily close if they are big enough", convergences are there "exists" a number in the set such that "the term is arbitrarily close to it if it is big enough". We simply want any sequence in a set(for instance, Q) "with good property"(i.e. Cauchy) to converge to some number, and hence we define the completion as such. In that way we can say "all sequence with good property converges to some number" (for instance, in R).

Comment: @mathma "weaker condition implied by convergence", like what for an example?

Comment: perhaps I should clarify that I understand what Cauchy sequences are and why they could be considered natural choice as I stated in the question. The only issue that I see is that the usual logic is "all convergent sequences are Cauchy so let's make the completion so that the converse is also true". I would like to see an argument that would make Cauchy sequences the "only" choice, how can we know we haven't thought of some other property that is weaker and not equivalent or implied by Cauchy?

Comment: So, really, you are asking why completeness is defined by Cauchy sequences, rather than why one constructs completions using Cauchy sequences?

Comment: @ZhenLin yes, you could state it that way. I am interested on why should one use Cauchy sequences for the definition of completeness.

Comment: @mathma Do you have any other idea of different definition for completeness?

Comment: @Acc-lab I have no examples for a different definition. But that is not the point. I want to see why/whether if I were to come up with a different definition I would be ultimately doing the same thing as Cauchy sequences.

Comment: The definition of a complete metric space already involves the notion of a Cauchy sequence. It's therefore no surprise that they enter the construction of the completion.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg the question was not to motivate the construction but the definition (the former is trivial enough). perhaps it is not so clear as it is stated, but a careful read should give you a better idea of what was asked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The purpose of defining a Cauchy sequence is that the property is (a) preserved under isometric maps, meaning that a sequence remains Cauchy if you extend or restrict the ambient metric space, and thus (b) is “intrinsic” to the sequence.

Note: By an “isometric map”, I mean a map $f$ from a metric space $(X, d)$ to a metric space $(Y, \rho)$ such that $\rho(f(x_1), f(x_2)) = d(x_1, x_2)$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$. An isometric map describes how $(X, d)$ exists as a metric space inside of $(Y, \rho)$.

Here’s a fact you can check, and I hope it answers your question.

> **Claim:** Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$. Then the sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $(X, d)$ iff there exists a metric space $(Y, \rho)$ and an isometric embedding $\iota: X \hookrightarrow Y$ such that the sequence $(\iota(x_n))$ is convergent in $(Y, \rho)$.

The forward direction is just the completion of a metric space. The backward direction follows because if $(\iota(x_n))$ is convergent, then it’s Cauchy, and so $(x_n)$ is also Cauchy.

In other words, a sequence is Cauchy iff there’s some extension of the metric space that makes the sequence convergent. A Cauchy sequence can be made convergent, but a non-Cauchy sequence can *never* be made convergent by extending the metric space.

Comment: that's actually a really satisfactory answer. Thank you!

Comment: You mean "convergent" in the claim?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg yes, good catch